# why my live-stream is not working in vs code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm

v16.13.2
PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\04-HTML-CSS> npm install live-server -g
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to `open`
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

changed 203 packages, and audited 204 packages in 2m

2 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Comment: Is this a tutorial? If not, as the error says, try running `npm audit fix --force`. Please format the code using three backslashes before and after your code leaving newlines after the first and the last of it. See [how to format your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.